# Adding to empty set

Tags: python

```
empty_set = set()
```

How would I use a loop to add 10 random integers, all from 10 to 30 inclusive, to the above empty set?

Also how do I use another loop to process the set that displays all elements of the set on one line separated by `**` and that counts how many elements are even and how many elements are odd and then displays the counts?

Trying to output it like something similar to below:

```
12**16**17**18**20**21**22**23**24**28**
Set has 7 even numbers and 3 odd numbers
```

From what heinst helped me with, I am trying to change the list to a set...is this right at all?

```
import random



numbers = set()
for _ in range(0, 10):
numbers.add(random.randrange(10, 30))
printStr = ''
evens = 0
odds = 0
for num in numbers:
printStr += '{0}**'.format(num)
if num % 2 == 0:
    evens += 1
else:
    odds += 1

print (printStr)

print ('Set has {0} even numbers and {1} odd numbers'.format(evens, odds))
```

Comment: Then go through a tutorial. **I have no idea** is not good enough reason.

Comment: Can't find any tutorials that are similar to this. Point me to one?

Comment: @AshleyThompson you can read through [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), written by Python's creator. At this point, it will probably help you more than a specific answer to your question.

Comment: @AshleyThompson You can read **any** tutorial. Since the question is so basic, it doesn't matter at all which one you pick.

Comment: Well thats not helpful at all. I have been reading through sets tutorials, and none of them demonstrate how to do this. If you can't show me, then link me to something useful if you can please.

Comment: `print("12**16**17**18**20**21**22**23**24**28**\nSet has 7 even numbers and 3 odd numbers")`

Comment: @AshleyThompson why a set? Why not a list? Lists are by far faster then sets in python

Comment: Thats the question. checkpoint in sets I am just begininng

Comment: @AshleyThompson I just dont feel like I would be helping if I gave you the answer, I think the best way would be to read up on Lists and start from there

Comment: It's a very simple question, I just wanted someone to write it out real quick and explain what it was doing so I can play around with it and learn it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really suggest that you sit down and read up on Python, but this is how I approached the problem. I added comments to explain each line.

```
import random

#list comprehension, but since you are new use uncommented  way
#numbers = [random.randrange(10, 30) for i in range(0, 10)]

#creates an empty list
numbers = []
#goes from 0 - 9, _ means no variable necessary, just looping a set number of times
for _ in range(0, 10):
    #generates a random number from 10 - 30 and appends it to the numbers list
    numbers.append(random.randrange(10, 30))

#creates an empty string and num of evens and odds at 0
printStr = ''
evens = 0
odds = 0
#for each number in numbers list
for num in numbers:
    #add to print string with number and two asterisks after it
    printStr += '{0}**'.format(num)
    #check if its even, if so increment even count
    if num % 2 == 0:
        evens += 1
    #if not, increment odd count
    else:
        odds += 1
#print string of all numbers and 2 asterisks after each number
print printStr
#print that the list has x evens and x odds
print 'List has {0} even numbers and {1} odd numbers'.format(evens, odds)
```

Comment: That was quick....thank you a lot, I am going to play around with it and see if I can create similar things. Can I comment back here if I have questions?

Comment: Yes of course, heinst will be your personal teacher for free.

Comment: @septi shots fired...i felt bad and wanted to help out a new programmer...but also was torn because this is just giving the answer rather than learning...the struggle....

Comment: It's just my opinion: you did not help at all. In fact you showed him a weird example and motivated him to come back at any time he's too lazy to learn something new on his own.

Comment: Thanks for being noob friendly @heinst. It did help.

Comment: @septi Im more curious now how you think my way is "strange"?

Comment: For one, `printStr = '**'.join('{0}'.format(x) for x in numbers)` would be more pythonic (and faster - concatenating strings in a loop is quadratic)

Comment: @heinst I have gone through this now the past couple hours, and understand it, but is there a way to make this a set instead of a list easy? I will edit my post now for what I change that I think works, but idk if it is right..

Comment: @AshleyThompson I'm still unsure why you want to use a set so much. Can you explain? And yes that's how you would convert it

Comment: It's not that I want to, it's just what the question was asking, I just wanted to see what the difference was, so apparently not much? I have heard that lists are a lot more efficient in things like this which I am guessing is true.

Comment: @AshleyThompson yes they are more efficient and a lot more common